# admob issue with titatinum alloy

Tags: titanium, admob, titanium-alloy

I am using titanium 3.x studio. I want to display google advertisement in my application.
For that i am using admob module for android.

My xml file settings are:

```
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"/>
    <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="13" android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>
    <tool-api-level>13</tool-api-level>
    </android>

    <modules>
        <module platform="android">ti.admob</module>
    </modules>
```

But im getting error Emulator process exited with code 1

please help me to get out of this thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update maxSdkVersion to 16 and tool-api-level to 16